# Is relation extraction considered a subtask of information extraction?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing

I'm currently trying to investigate the relationship between relation extraction (RE) and event extraction (EE). Doing more reading on the two tasks has caused me to question my initial belief that RE is within the task of information extraction (IE).

The reason why I believe so is because RE is typically modeled as a prediction task where a model is given two entities and tasked to predict the relationship between them, whereas EE seems to be typically modeled as a sequence labeling task to extract an event trigger and the event's arguments.

More formally, I believe the two can be modeled as:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{RE} & \rightarrow p(r\ \vert\ e_1, e_2, c) \\
\text{EE} & \rightarrow p(l_i \vert\ c)\quad \text{where}\ l \in \{\text{null}, \text{trigger}, \text{argument}\}
\end{align}
$$

where $r$ denotes the relation, $e_1$ and $e_2$ each denote the two entities, $c$ denotes the provided context, and $l_i$ refers to the label of the $i$th token given context $c$.

Anyway, this has led me to believe that RE and EE are fundamentally different tasks, and whether RE is even considered to be within the larger umbrella of IE. Any opinions or pointers to resources/papers are appreciated. Thanks.